# TFS - How do I clone a project so I can rollback the original?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a project in TFS that has been live for a year. In June we made our final release (we labelled the sources) before we began a massive 3 month overhaul during which the live site would not change.

Unfortunately we are now required to make a change to the live site and the codebase has changed significantly. What I want to do ideally is check-out by label the final release (June) into another folder and check that in to TFS to create another project. This way my team can work on both projects.

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a branch. This doesn't need to be in a new project. In fact it would be better if it wasn't, however depending on your folder structure keeping it in the same project might not be an option.

Right click on the root of the folder you want to branch. This should be the folder highest in your folder structure that contains all of the code you want to modify.

On the right click menu select "Branching and Merging" and then "Branch"

Choose a sensible location for the new branch.

In the dropdown select "Label" then choose the appropriate selection. 
[image]
Hit branch. This will create a new branch from the label and you will be able use the new branch to modify your live code base

Comment: I went with this, and it was simple enough to do. Thank you very much!